# What does ContextStoreAgent do, and how can its database errors be fixed?

Tags: macos, big-sur, error, siri, logs

On my macOS 11.5.2 (Big Sur) system, the logs are full of the following error reported by a process called `ContextStoreAgent`:

```
CoreData: PostSaveMaintenance:
performPostSaveTasks threw something (1). ex = Fatal error.  
The database at /Users/jstarek/Library/Application 
Support/Knowledge/knowledgeC.db is corrupted.  
SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed'
```

(lines wrapped for readability)

I can't find detailed information about this, apart from the fact that the `Knowledge` folder seems to be used for custom Siri information.

So, how can I fix the above error, and where can I find technical documentation about the `ContextStoreAgent` service?